# ES6 Asynchronous promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

i'm still beginner in ES6 .
i'm trying to create a function which sends a http(s) request with the a logic that when You send a http(s) request. If there is 5 or more ongoing requests, you have to wait until one
of them is completed then you can process next request.
When the response code is not 200, you need to retry 3 times. If the response code after
retrying 3 times is still not 200 then the error function should be executed.
also i wanna  Receive the JSON data of the response body as a function argument.

```
function httpGet(url) {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    // Success
                    resolve(this.response);
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong (404 etc.)
                    reject(new Error(this.statusText));
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function () {
                reject(new Error(
                    'XMLHttpRequest Error: '+this.statusText));
            };
            request.open('GET', url);
            request.send();
        });
}
```

this what i have done so far .
Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I created a new promise , but i'm stick at the first part of define the ongoing requests

Comment: `Please show what you have tried so far` - ditto, if you want to receive help from a fellow developer you have to show the money. We are here to help you not for code for you.

Comment: i added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general queue for promise callbacks:

```
// Helper to run a callback when a promise either resolves, or rejects.
function fin(promise, callback){
  return promise.then(
    value => (callback(), Promise.resolve(value)),
    error => (callback(), Promise.reject(error))
  );
}

function makeQueue(maxParallel){
  const queue = [];
  let inProgress = 0;

  // Run the oldest queued task.
  function run(){
    const {resolve, reject, callback} = queue.shift();

    inProgress++;
    return fin(callback(), () => inProgress--).then(resolve, reject);
  }

  // If more tasks can run in parallel, start them
  function dequeue(){
    if (queue.length > 0 && inProgress < maxParallel) run().then(dequeue);
  }

  return function(callback){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      queue.push({resolve, reject, callback});
      dequeue();
    });
  }
}
```

Then use the queue to queue `httpGet`:

```
const queue = makeQueue(5);

// Queue up httpGet calls.
function httpGetWithQueue(url){
  return queue(() => httpGet(url));
}
```

Then call that with retry logic:

```
// Call httpGet with queued processing, with the request tried
// up to three times.
function httpGetWithRetry(url){
  let result = Promise.reject();

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    result = result.catch(() => httpGetWithQueue(url));
  }
  return result;
}
```